# Do rejected edits impact the editor's reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Is there any threshold for rejected edits that causes one's reputation decrease or some other loss?

In other words, I suggested *N* edits and all *N* edits were rejected. What will be the impact on my reputation or what will happen that is bad thing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there any threshold for rejected edits that causes one's reputation decrease or some other loss?

No. You can't lose reputation from rejected suggested edits, as you never gained reputation from them in the first place (they would need to be *approved* not rejected for that to happen).

What *can* happen is that the accout will get banned from suggested edits - in particular if many of them get rejected and not many accepted.

tl;dr

You don't lose reputation, but it is a bad thing.

Comment: banned for how long?

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon one week, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284) it's the first bullet under "Why is the "edit" link disabled?"

Comment: Yeah thanks! it is making sense now.