# Do declined flags impact the flagger's reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, flags, declined-flags

Is there any threshold for declined flags that causes one's reputation decrease or some other loss?

In other words, I flagged N posts and all N flags were declined. What will be the impact on my reputation or what will happen that is bad thing?

Forked from: [Do rejected edits impact the editor's reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276425/do-rejected-edits-impact-the-editors-reputation)

Comment: the person who downvoted, can you share the reason please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, flags have no impact on the reputation for the user raising that flag. Also, the outcome of the flag doesn't influence reputation either. (The outcome does contribute to a flag ban)

A flag can have effect on the owner of the post being flagged, like a spam or abuse flag will cause a reputation loss, for example [6 spam flags have a 100 reputation penalty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/245360).